# How to export Get-ADUser results to CSV without quotes and with additional blank fields?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, csv

I'm trying to export some data from our Active Directory to a .csv file. The file needs to have certain columns (because the tool which will import the .csv file is very strict and I cannot alter it) which I don't have, and doesn't process quotes.

At the moment I have the following (with more fields, but this is an example):

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {(enabled -eq $true)} -Properties * | Select-Object -Property @{Name="FirstName";Expression={$_."GivenName"}},  
    @{Name="LastName";Expression={$_."SurName"}},  
    @{Name="UserID";Expression={$_."EmployeeId"}} | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -Path Data.csv
```

This exports a .csv file with every field placed in double quotes, so my first question is how do I prevent these double quotes?
I've found a -UseQuotes option available as of PowerShell 7, but I cannot alter the version of PowerShell (altering software is not allowed on the server).

My second question is: how can I add a blank column to the list above? I've tried adding

```
@{Name="Blank";Expression={$_.""}},
"",
Something_That_Doesnt_Exist
```

But those either give an error or a blank value enclosed in double quotes.

Any idea how I can get the desired output, without processing the .csv file after it has been created?

Answer (score 0):

To export without quotes use the `-UseQuotes Never` parameter.

For  blank field, use : `@{Name="Blank";Expression={$null}}`.
Or, if that is output as the string `$null` then use a string such as `" "`.

Comment: Thanks for the blank field suggestion, I'll try it. But as I stated in my question, I cannot use the -UseQuotes parameter because that is only available as of Powershell 7. I'm on Powershell 5, and I cannot alter the version of Powershell on the server.

Comment: Sorry for missing out on this fact. Try to pass the result through something like `Select-Object -Property field1, field2, " ", fields3`